# Is G++ smart enough to optimize this out?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, g++

Imagine the following situation:

```
struct Args
{
  bool arg;
};
void thing(Args arg)
{
  if(arg.arg)
    cout<<"arg.arg is true\n";
  else
    cout<<"arg.arg is false\n";
}
int main()
{
  Args a;
  a.arg=false;
  thing(a);
}
```

Is the compiler smart enough to remove `switch`, `if`, and `else` branches that will obviously never be called over the course of the program? Must the variable in question that controls these statements be `const`? And lastly, is the right thing to do not to use variables at all but to use the preproccesor (I'm scared by the thought of that code)?

Just to clarify, the real situation is that I'm writing a class where the programmer can choose whether to enable a certain feature. Disabling the feature can save a lot of processing time on the server some bandwidth between the class and the server. I'm trying to figure out whether I should use a variable as a constructor argument, a preproccessor derivative, or some other solution. I don't want to ever even consider the logic branch if the feature is enabled if it is disabled. I know that with the preproccessor solution will do this, but I want to avoid that mass use of `#ifdef`, `#elseif` and I want to be able to reuse one complied shared object. Source being open to the programmer is no problem as this is going to be open-source.

EDIT: I tested the bellow compile line and looked at the assembly. I can't make full sense of it, but I did see a jump instruction (`jne`). Here is the assembly if anyone can make it out:

```
    .file   "blah.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "arg.arg is true\n"
.LC1:
    .string "arg.arg is false\n"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _Z5thing4Args
    .type   _Z5thing4Args, @function
_Z5thing4Args:
.LFB1003:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    cmpb    $0, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L5
    movl    $17, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    leave
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
.L5:
    .cfi_restore_state
    movl    $16, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    .cfi_restore 5
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1003:
    .size   _Z5thing4Args, .-_Z5thing4Args
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1004:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $17, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1004:
    .size   main, .-main
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__I__Z5thing4Args, @function
_GLOBAL__I__Z5thing4Args:
.LFB1009:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, 8(%esp)
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, (%esp)
    call    __cxa_atexit
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1009:
    .size   _GLOBAL__I__Z5thing4Args, .-_GLOBAL__I__Z5thing4Args
    .section    .ctors,"aw",@progbits
    .align 4
    .long   _GLOBAL__I__Z5thing4Args
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_oncePiPFvvE,pthread_once
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_getspecificj,pthread_getspecific
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_setspecificjPKv,pthread_setspecific
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_createPmPK14pthread_attr_tPFPvS3_ES3_,pthread_create
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_joinmPPv,pthread_join
    .weakref    _ZL21__gthrw_pthread_equalmm,pthread_equal
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_selfv,pthread_self
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_detachm,pthread_detach
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_cancelm,pthread_cancel
    .weakref    _ZL19__gthrw_sched_yieldv,sched_yield
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_lock
    .weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_trylockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_trylock
    .weakref    _ZL31__gthrw_pthread_mutex_timedlockP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_mutex_timedlock
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_mutex_unlockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_unlock
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_initP15pthread_mutex_tPK19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutex_init
    .weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_destroyP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_destroy
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_broadcastP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_broadcast
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_cond_signalP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_signal
    .weakref    _ZL25__gthrw_pthread_cond_waitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_cond_wait
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_timedwaitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_cond_timedwait
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_cond_destroyP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_destroy
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE,pthread_key_create
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_deletej,pthread_key_delete
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_initP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_init
    .weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_settypeP19pthread_mutexattr_ti,pthread_mutexattr_settype
    .weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_destroyP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_destroy
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

EDIT: I looked at the assembly more after adding `asm("#aksdjfh")` as suggested bellow, and I have found that the compiler does not get rid of it. So are `#ifdef`s the only option? Or is the `jne` instruction something that I can effectively ignore for performance?

Comment: `$ g++ -O3 -S test.cpp -o test.s`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Great. Would you post that as an answer and explain the flags? I know that `-03` is optimization level 3, but that is `-S`?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: That's not an answer.  He's giving you the means by which you can find out the answer yourself. The `-S` flag is to output assembly.

Comment: It will probably inline that short function and optimize the if out. If it's a long function, that might not happen.

Comment: `-S` outputs the generated assembly code.

Comment: The question could be are developer is smart enough to avoid using so many 'if's' in his program?

Comment: `-S` creates the assembly output. You need to check if the branch is optimized away

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Ok? How? I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: @AlexTheo: Did you read the last paragraph of my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it out yourself:

```
$ g++ -O3 -S test.cpp -o test.s
```

`-O3` turns optimizations on, `-S` tells the compiler to stop after generating assembly code, and `-o` selects where to place the output. Then you can inspect the "test.s" file and see if it optimized it or not. Obviously this requires some knowledge of assembly. You may also want `-masm=intel` if you, like me, find AT&T syntax unreadable and prefer Intel syntax.

It might help to add lines like `asm("# this is something")` to the code. These will appear as comments in the generated assembly, which may make it easier to identify the portions you're interested in.

On my machine, a snapshot of GCC 4.8 does not seem to optimize that dead code away. I added one of those asm comments to each branch to recognize them and it generated this:

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "arg.arg is true\n"
.LC1:
    .string "arg.arg is false\n"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  _Z5thing4Args
    .type   _Z5thing4Args, @function
_Z5thing4Args:
.LFB1215:
    .cfi_startproc
    sub esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    cmp BYTE PTR [esp+32], 0
    jne .L6
#APP
# 13 "test.cpp" 1
    This is the false branch
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 17
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    add esp, 28
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    .cfi_restore_state
#APP
# 10 "test.cpp" 1
    This is the true branch
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 16
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    add esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1215:
    .size   _Z5thing4Args, .-_Z5thing4Args
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1216:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    mov BYTE PTR [esp], 0
    call    _Z5thing4Args
    xor eax, eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1216:
    .size   main, .-main
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5thing4Args, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5thing4Args:
.LFB1367:
    .cfi_startproc
    sub esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    call    __cxa_atexit
    add esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1367:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5thing4Args, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5thing4Args
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 4
    .long   _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5thing4Args
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.0 20120311 (experimental)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

If you look for those comments, you'll find them both followed by a call to some `std::cout` member function.

This happens because as is, the function is visible on other translation units: if you now make a `nasty.cpp` file with a declaration `void thing(Args arg);` and a call with the value `true`, the code *must* exist.

So I experimented a bit further. If I mark the function as `static`, meaning it is internal to that translation unit, GCC does indeed optimize the dead code away:

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "arg.arg is false\n"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1216:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
#APP
# 13 "test.cpp" 1
    This is the false branch
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    xor eax, eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1216:
    .size   main, .-main
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1367:
    .cfi_startproc
    sub esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    call    __cxa_atexit
    add esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1367:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 4
    .long   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.0 20120311 (experimental)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

You won't find "This is the true branch" in that code. Also, note how the false branch was moved into the `main` function and the `thing` function doesn't exist anymore. GCC simply inlined the function's code and didn't bother generating it because it's not going to be used anywhere else now that I've added `static`.

If I mark it as `inline`, it will still be visible outside, but apparently that's enough of a hint for GCC to optimize it too. However, if you do this, you'll have to make sure  other translation units see the same definition, so that code can be generated as necessary for each of them.

Comment: How much overhead is the comparison? If the code dosn't execute, is the comparison anything I have to worry about?

Comment: That would be hard to answer. I'd say that in general, no, it's not worth worrying about one comparison. Of course, there are situations where it may matter, but it's usually better find what code is expensive by running benchmarks.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I am pretty surprised gcc does not inline this (trivial) function in `O3` even without the `static`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, I was expecting that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no (at least not the version of gcc I have handy).

The long answer is pretty much as R. Martinho Fernandes has said: to figure out things like this, have the compiler produce assembly language output (`-S` on the gcc command line), then examine the assembly language it produces. In this case, the relevant part of that looks like this:

Data:

```
LC0:
    .ascii "arg.arg is true\12\0"
LC1:
    .ascii "arg.arg is false\12\0"
```

Code:

```
LCFI2:
    cmpb    $0, 8(%ebp)
    jne L5
    movl    $17, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC1, 4(%esp)
    movl    $__ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    leave
    ret

L5:
    movl    $16, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $__ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    leave
```

The `cmpb $0, 8(%ebp)` is essentially `if (whatever==false)`. Depending on the result of that comparison, it's going to continue executing the code below LCFI2, which prints out LC1, or else L5, which prints out LC0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about gcc, but Clang is... so gcc is probably too!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Args
{
  bool arg;
};
static void thing(Args arg)
{
  if(arg.arg)
    printf("arg.arg is true\n");
  else
    printf("arg.arg is false\n");
}
int main()
{
  Args a;
  a.arg=false;
  thing(a);
}
```

Note: using iostreams clutter the output so I changed it to `printf` style printing. I also added `static` to avoid emitting the function, it was still inlined without it.

The following IR is generated:

```
@str = internal constant [17 x i8] c"arg.arg is false\00"

define i32 @main() nounwind uwtable {
  %puts.i = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([17 x i8]* @str, i64 0, i64 0)) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}
```

You will remark that:

- `thing` is completely inlined
- `thing` is not emitted (`static` effect)
- `"arg.arg is true\n"` is not even stored (`static` effect)

The optimization name you are looking for is *Constant Propagation*.

Comment: Well, as I found above, GCC sure didn't get rid of it at all. Back to the `#ifdef`s I go.

Comment: Or you could switch to compiling with Clang/LLVM

Answer (score 1):

That type of optimization is actually asking quite a bit, and the answer might be different when the code gets just a little more complex.

> Just to clarify, the real situation is that I'm writing a class where the programmer can choose whether to enable a certain feature. Disabling the feature can save a lot of processing time on the server some bandwidth between the class and the server. I'm trying to figure out whether I should use a variable as a constructor argument, a preproccessor derivative, or some other solution.

You might consider using [Policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) as popularized by Andre Alexandrescu.

Comment: Policies looks like exactly what I wanted. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if full path is visible to the compiler (and optimization is enabled). You can verify that with GCC `-S` flag. Link-time optimization (`-flto` for latest GCC versions) might do that too, but I never checked.

#### Edit 0:

As an alternative to `#ifdef` magic in the source consider segregating functionality into different implementation files and use `make(1)` to pick the right one at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors that may allow or not the compiler to optimize function calls.

First of all, there's no proof that the 'thing' function isn't called anywhere else, therefore it will certainly not be inlined automatically, unless it has been declared static (to make it local to the current translation unit).
You can give those hints to the compiler by explicitely adding the `inline` modifier when declaring the 'thing' function.
The inline modifier will allow the compiler to expand the function's code where it is called.
In your case, inlining would certainly optimize out the code under the if, and only the second "cout" would survive.

I would however tend to avoid counting on such a behaviour for compile-time feature enabling/disabling.

Basically, it makes the code's main logic indistinguishable from configuration. That will make debugging more complicated.

While I tend to agree that many #ifdef/#endif are not quite pretty, they're extremely common for situations like yours.

You have another solution, that I personnally tend to use when possible:

If the 'features' you need to enable/disable can be isolated well enough, you can create classes or functions that represent each possible behaviour.
Put each variation in their own cpp file, and use your build configuration system to choose which file to compile at build-time.

Comment: Making local (to the TU) functions `static` is usually better.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that, I usually am very careful of that in my own code :)

Comment: compilers can inline any function, and won't always inline a function marked with `inline`.  `inline` means it can be defined in multiple TUs.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers answer the question directly,  here's another way to work around your issue: you can use templates.  These will always be optimized as you wish, because they're *technically* two different functions.

```
    template<bool do_thing_1>
    void thing(std::integral_constant<bool, do_thing_1>)
    {
        if (do_thing_1)
            cout<<"arg.arg is true\n";
        else
            cout<<"arg.arg is false\n";
    }
    int main() {
        thing(std::true_type()); 
        thing(std::false_type());
    }
```

If you want it to depend on a variable, then there's no optimizing it out, what you have is best.

Comment: Mwhahaha. GCC can optimize what he has, if only you give it the right hints: either the function is not visible outside this TU (`static`), or all TUs will see a definition (`inline`).

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, since this `template` function must also be in all TUs, that makes this a very silly solution.